# Is there a possible N+1 issue when using nested select?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a one-to-one map between two tables. If using nested select, will it cause the N+1 problem? Even no N+1 problem, will it cause more SQL sent to database?

How to compare with nested resultset using join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it all depends on your objective.

In both cases you map the second table into an object association.

Nested select indeed causes the N+1 problem, but allows using lazy loading, then fetching only required data, just in time it is needed. Then potentially only a couple of simple queries.

Query with join will fetch everything in a single but most costly query.